# Does dataWithContentsOfURL cache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, caching

I am trying to figure out if `dataWithContentsOfURL` caches the contents, so that if in the code:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://testsite.com/img/%@.png"
,imgName]]]];
```

a line would follow:

```
UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://testsite.com/img/%@.png"
,imgName]]]];
```

Would that require going to the network again?

Comment: You can save and use the NSData

Comment: oov.. one moment what is the need of 2 UIImage with same image content?You can use the same anywhere right?

Comment: img2 will only be called upon a subsequent request decided in runtime. The URL is concluded on runtime as well. I wanted to know if my app would need net access again if it happens to access the same URL twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not cached.

I recommend you start using ASIHTTPRequest or AFNetwork frameworks. They allow you to cache.

You have some ways to do caching if you do NSMutableURLRequest, but not great ones.

You should also not use XWithContentOfURL as they tie up your main thread, unless you use threads or GCD, things you get for free if you use the above frameworks